# How to create a base class of DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have created a base class for the `DateTimePicker` in vb.net Winforms. The `OnCreateControl` method fires ok but I cannot get the events to work. This shows the code to create, check for delete and space keys.

```vb
Class mydtp
    Inherits DateTimePicker

    Protected Overrides Sub onCreateControl()
        MyBase.OnCreateControl()
        Me.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        Me.CustomFormat = "--/--/----"
        Me.Value = "01/01/1900"  ' Abitrary date
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the problem. I have tried this with `KeyPress`, `KeyDown`, `KeyUp`, `KeyPreview` but when I add the control to the toolbox and onto a form none of the keys respond.

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyUp(ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnKeyUp(e)

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
        Me.CustomFormat = "--/--/----"
        Me.Value = "01/01/1900"  ' Abitrary date
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Space Then
        Me.CustomFormat = DateTimePickerFormat.Short
        Me.Value = DateTime.Now
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to put as much of the behavior in the base class and only things like `MinDate`, `MaxDate` in the form where the MyDTP is used.

Regards
Graham

Comment: The control must be selected/focused to handle its key events.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply but not sure what you are saying, of course it has focus, I add the control to a form tab/click on it and press space but nothing happens the event does not get fired by the look of it.

Comment: Does this even compile or it's a pseudo code? This `Me.CustomFormat = DateTimePickerFormat.Short` is wrong. The `DateTimePickerFormat` is the type of the `Format` property. Replace it with `Me.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"`. I hope you aren't doing this `Me.Value = "01/01/1900"`.. In other words, choose the `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` format and change the `CustomFormat` property in the `OnKeyUp` method override. Also, you could move what in the `OnCreateControl` to the default constructor. `Sub New() ... End Sub`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check again but yes Intellisense reports datetimepickerformat.short as a choice. I am looking to show --/--/---- when the screen first loads (which it does) press spacebar or dropdown to change this to a valid date by setting format to short and value to date.now. Pressing delete will blank the dtp. Sounds simple enough. I can copy this code into a form without using inheritance and it works. I am looking to do this in a base control so it simplifies the design. That doesn't work.

Comment: Obviously you're not paying attention and you don't spend any time reading the documentation. Again, [CustomFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property is of type **String** not one of the `DateTimePickerFormat` values used to set the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) property.

Comment: If you set instead the `Format` property in the `OnKeyUp` method which makes more sense, then this is the problem because doing so recreates the control's handle, the base class calls the `RecreateHandle` method for that. Which invokes the `OnCreateControl` method again which sets the `Format` property to `Custom`. You'll never get the `DateTimePickerFormat.Short` value set. Clear?